# Does NSInvocation retain self, _cmd, and assigned arguments?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I added NSInvocation to a dictionary to execute some commands I need, but I am afraid of the NSInvocation will retain the arguments it obtained, for example, self, _cmd, and the arguments I set. When I add NSInvocation to a dictionary, the dictionary will retain the NSInvocation, and does it retains those arguments too ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`NSInvocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does ***not*** retain the target, selector or arguments unless you send it the [`retainArguments`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000212-retainArguments) message, which will set `argumentsRetained` to `YES`.

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSInvocation/retainArguments), it doesn't retain the target by default either: "For efficiency, newly created NSInvocations don’t retain or copy their arguments, nor do they retain their targets or copy C strings."